# Does Azure support AIX?

Tags: unix, azure, aix

I'm thinking that I could use Azure IaaS to host some Unix machines. Can I upload and use an AIX 6.1 64 bits virtual machine to Azure?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is no. As of today, you can use Linux distributions from Canonical (Ubuntu), SUSE, OpenLogic (CentOS) and Oracle. To see the supported version list and get more information, see http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-endorsed-distributions/

Answer (score 1):

Just for the reference, the answer is yes now ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/example-scenario/mainframe/migrate-aix-workloads-to-skytap)).